# Does Microsoft Money Work in Windows 11?

Tags: software, microsoft-money

Does Microsoft Money work on Windows 11? I have used it on previous OS versions but want confirmation before upgrading to 11.

***Update:  I installed Ms Money on Windows 11 Pro (upgrade from Windows 10 Pro). As far as I can tell it functions the same as it did in Windows 10.***

Comment: If you somehow need access to Microsoft Money for a long time, it may be time to ask someone more technically competent and help you create a Virtual Machine to run it. I'm currently running Windows 3.1 (DOS 5.0) inside of Windows 10 that's running on a Macbook Air.

Comment: Voted to re-open. This question is not seeking product or service recommendations -- it is asking a question about specific personal finance software.

Comment: [Questions about the use of personal financial software are on-topic](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/127/10997). This should be reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Microsoft Money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Money) was discontinued in 2009 so obviously it is not "officially" supported on Windows 11. However, many people used it on Windows 10 and [some users](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/microsoft-money-2005-works.322/) report that it works just fine with Windows 11.

[This user](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/microsoft-money-2005-works.322/post-20565) said the following about Money not working on Windows 11:

> Money requires Internet Explorer which is missing in Windows 11 so
> that could the reason why [it doesn't work,] and unless one used the patched mnyob99.dll,
> there can also be other problems

Best case: you have to do some work-arounds to get it to run (downloading an edited .dll or similar).

Note: I don't personally use Microsoft Money.